# HttpTestingController tests for correct x-www-form-urlencoded fields via HttpParams

Tags: javascript, angular, testing

I'm looking to use HttpTestingController to test that the correct set of fields are included in a POST request that my Service sends via a HttpClient.

**web-form.ts**

```
export class WebFormService {

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

public submitForm(fields): Observable<any> {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  const body = new HttpParams()
    .set('_to',  environment.FORM_RECIPIENT)
    .set('source', 'mysite');

  for (let key of fields) {
      body.set(key, fields[key]);
  }

  return this.httpClient.post(
    environment.FORM_URL,
    body,
    {headers}
  );
}
```

**web-form.spec.ts**

```
it('sends a POST request via the HttpClient service', () => {
    const testFields = {
      name: 'test contributor',
      message: 'my message',
      email: 'test@tester.com'
    };

    webFormService.submitForm(testFields).subscribe();

    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(environment.FORM_URL);
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');
    expect(req.request.headers.get('Content-Type')).toEqual('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    // Here I'd like to make assertions about the fields that data being posted.

    req.flush('');
});
```

The HttpRequest is url-encoding the `body` on so `req.request.body` is a properly url-encoded string.

Is there any good option to test without resorting to de-encoding request body and comparing objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the `HttpParams` object is still available via the HttpRequest `body` property.

It was a little confusing and hard to spot because `HttpParams.toString()` function performs the urlencoding, which in turns causes the test runner to emit the encoded string.

So, it is nevertheless possible to utilise `HttpParams` functions to obtain the keys and values that the Service under test is supplying to the `HttpClient`.

For example...

```
const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(environment.CONTRIBUTION_FORM_ENDPOINT);
expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');
expect(req.request.headers.get('Content-Type')).toEqual('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

const expectedFormKeys = Object.keys(testFields).concat(['_to', 'source']);
expect(req.request.body.keys().sort()).toEqual(expectedFormKeys.sort());
// ... and so on
```